# Hadoop slaves file regard IP as hostname?

Tags: hadoop

I have a ubuntu server VM in virtual box(in Mac OSX). And I configured a Hadoop Cluster via docker: 1 master(172.17.0.3), 2 slave nodes(172.17.0.4, 172.17.0.6). After run "./sbin/start-dfs.sh" under Hadoop home folder, I found below error in datanode machine:

```
Datanode denied communication with namenode because hostname cannot be 
resolved (ip=172.17.0.4, hostname=172.17.0.4): DatanodeRegistration(0.0.0.0, 
datanodeUuid=4c613e35-35b8-41c1-a027-28589e007e78, infoPort=50075, 
ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-55;cid=CID-9bac5643-1f9f-4bc0-abba-
34dba4ddaff6;nsid=1748115706;c=0)
```

Because docker does not support bidirectional name linking and further more, my docker version does not allow editing /etc/hosts file, So I use IP address to set name node and slaves. Following is my slaves file:

```
172.17.0.4
172.17.0.6
```

After searching on google and stackoverflow, no solution works for my problem. However I guess that Hadoop Namenode regard 172.17.0.4 as a "hostname", so it reports "hostname can not be resolved" where "hostname=172.17.0.4". 
Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a solution, which proved my suppose:

1.upgrade my docker to 1.4.1, following instructions from: https://askubuntu.com/questions/472412/how-do-i-upgrade-docker.

2.write IP=>hostname mappings of master and slaves into /etc/hosts

3.use hostname instead of ip address in Hadoop slaves file.

4."run ./sbin/start-dfs.sh"

5.Done!